# Invalid Signature - On publish products (using POST method) to Magento

Tags: java, magento

hi i am trying to POST products to Magento by below code

```
JSONObject productJson = new JSONObject();
              JSONObject productParameJson = new JSONObject();
              productParameJson.put("sku", "Chair100");
              productParameJson.put("name", "Chair");
              productParameJson.put("price", "100");
              productParameJson.put("status", "1");
              productParameJson.put("visibility", "1");
              productJson.put("product", productParameJson);
              OAuthRequest oauthRequestPost = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "http://magentohost/api/rest" + "/products");
              oauthRequestPost.addHeader("Content_Type", "application/json");
              oauthRequestPost.addPayload(productJson.toString());
              service.signRequest(accessToken2, oauthRequestPost);
              Response apiResponsePost = oauthRequestPost.send();
              System.out.println(apiResponsePost.getCode());
              System.out.println(apiResponsePost.getBody());
```

But receives below error

```
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":401,"message":"oauth_problem=signature_invalid"}]}}
```

And in the same way if i try to GET the products lists using below code , i get lists of products.

```
 OAuthRequest oauthRequest = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "http://Magentohost/api/rest" + "/products");
                  service.signRequest(accessToken2, oauthRequest);
                  Response apiResponse = oauthRequest.send();
                  System.out.println(apiResponse.getCode());
                  System.out.println(apiResponse.getBody());
```

What am i doing wrong in POST method , please do help me in above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve above by using a dependency below:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
        <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And modified code as mentioned [here](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava/wiki/getting-started)